# Marshalling C# Jagged Array to C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to marshal a 2D C# jagged array (`double[][] jaggedArray`) to a C++ dll where i've specified the receiving variable to be a `double**`.

However, i'm getting the message:

> There is no marshaling support for
>   nested arrays.

Short of flattening the jagged array is there a way to use jagged arrays from C# in a C++ dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using low level Marshal class methods, it is possible to marshal any type to unmanaged memory. For example, for every double[] array in jaggedArray, allocate unmanaged memory block with Marshal.AllocHGlobal, and copy array members to it using Marshal.Copy Method (Double[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32) method. AllocHGlobal returns IntPtr type, which can be passed to C++ method as poiner, double* in this case.

Comment: fyi, the "update" section of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419367/p-invoke-with-2d-array-of-double-marshalling-data-between-c-sharp-and-c?noredirect=1#comment93728345_53419367 contains details of using this answer including how to attach the extracted rows to the outer jagged array pointer.  it also includes the dllimport statement and c++ function signature side of the equation that was needed to make input and output marshalling of jagged array work.