# Wrong Marshalling from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I have the following struct (On C) :

```
typedef struct Piece
{
    ePieceType PieceType;//enum
    ePlayer Player;//enum
    int IsFirstMove;
} sPiece;
```

(On C#):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Piece
{
    public PieceTypeEnum PieceType; //same enum order like ePieceType 
    public PlayerEnum Player; //same enum order like ePlayer 
    public int IsFirstMove;
}
```

I have the following function that I want to export :

```
__declspec(dllexport) void InitBoard(sPiece board[8][8]);
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("chess_api.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void InitBoard([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]Piece[][] board);
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I think I didn't marshal the array as well, Can you help me?

Comment: You've got a jagged array in C but a multidimensional array in C#,  those are not the same thing.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, ty! I changed it and now I get another error, I edited my question.

Comment: The exception is giving you the details.  You can't do what you want to do with a array declaration in C#.  In C arrays are just pointers, so you could declare InitBoard(IntPtr) and make sure you pass in a block of memory of the right size.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327196/problem-marshalling-c-sharp-jagged-array-to-c) could be helpful for manually marshalling the array.

Comment: Try [DllImport("chess_api.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void InitBoard([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=64)] Piece[][] board);

Comment: Just declare it Piece[] and pass an array with 64 elements.

Comment: @jlvaquero. it's not help.. ty anyway!

Comment: @HansPassant, there is way to do that without changing the C code?

Comment: @Xenolightning, But how I declare the pinvoke function?

Comment: Why do you think you have to change the C code?  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: @HansPassant, cuase i allready try and it's not work

Comment: Ah, yes, the dreaded "it's not work" exception.  Abandon all hope :(

Comment: @HansPassant. Finally, the proposal you gave helped me, you were right !! :) Thank you so much, you can upload it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

> Just declare it Piece [] and pass an array with 64 elements

Posted in comments by Hans Passant(but somehow did not raise it as an answer).